# NavMesh won't bake at all

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I've attempted to bake a Navigation Mesh in `Unity3D` on a plane with no success. I haven't had this problem until recently, around the `2020.1` release date. I set the plane to navigation static, walkable, and baked the navigation mesh with the plane selected. A `NavMesh` object was created. The 'Source Bounds Extent' becomes very small after baking. The navigation mesh does not appear on the screen at all, when normally it should appear in blue. Wondering if anyone else had this problem recently or if there is something I can do to correct it.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a problem I've had very recently also but I have fixed it by turning on Gizmos. The Navmesh is actually there, but you just cannot see it. Turn on Gizmos (at the top of the scene window) to see the Navmesh fully baked! If the above suggestion does not work, try checking that the object is static.

Comment: If this suggestion worked, please accept this answer as it could help the community at large. If this answer does not work, please tell me as I may be able to help you.

Comment: This was my issue ty!

Comment: So simple but worked.

Answer (score 10):

Try checking the Walkable layer is it static or not, since it must be static

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by duplicating the gameobject I have my tilemaps in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable all other objects in your scene. then bake your active static mesh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also, had the same problem, I put a group of pieces to static mesh, then baked, and it did nothing.  So, I tried the save button, then when I tried another group and made it static mesh and hit the bake button it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I noticed that in the same folder as the scene, a new folder with NavMesh had been created but I couldn't see any sign of it in the Scene view. I had to close the Scene Window and re-open it and there was the nav mesh visual.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving a scene before baking. It won't work if there is no scene present.